# Do we ever see the aliens from "If Wishes Were Horses" again? (DS9)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Title kind of covers it.  Do they ever make a second appearance?  Do we ever learn who they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest I can find is two mentions on Memory Beta, the non-canon Star Trek wiki.  And neither of them is about the aliens, just references back to the episode.

From the [episode page](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/If_Wishes_Were_Horses),

> The events of "If Wishes Were Horses" would later be mentioned in the
>   novels *Fallen Heroes*, *Proud Helios*, *Devil in the Sky* and *Wrath of the
>   Prophets*.

And from the page on [Rumpelstiltskin](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Rumpelstiltskin),

> In 2370, Molly called Quark an old gnome like Rumpelstiltskin. Odo
>   became agitated when he heard, being reminded of the events that took
>   place on the station. (DS9 novel: *Fallen Heroes*)

However, the [baseball given to Sisko](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Baseball_%28object%29) by the Buck Bokai alien in this episode gains great thematic importance as the series evolves.